# php 8.0+ Errors still displaying

Tags: php, php-8.1

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
error_reporting('display_errors', 'Off');
```

these are some of the options i found on the net, but none of them working

The error is:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'testing124' for key 'user'`

Basically, 'existing user' error, and of course I'm doing it on purpose to solve the error display, to make sure if I miss something, it's not shown to the user.

Please suggest any options

Trying to mainly stop the errors from displaying to the user.

Comment: On the file where error/exception occur, add `var_dump(ini_get('display_errors'));` before that line to see if it really is turned off or not. If it is not, try to use [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to see what files are loaded and check each file that where these ini settings were modified.

Comment: Is PHP itself displaying the error or a user script does?

Comment: @vee first one is giving string(1) "1"... and second one empty array

Comment: php script it's PDO error @shingo

Comment: @Kevin_woob you should disable error reporting in the top most file being called. I mean in the very first script that's executed.

Comment: That `var_dump()` showing `'1'` means it is displaying errors in the ini somewhere but the `debug_backtrace()` from where error occur should not showing empty array.